# MEAN template project and/or recommended file hierarchy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, qunit, meanjs

I've recently gotten into development in MEAN stack. I burned through a [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/), which seemed easy enough, if oversimplified. I've read a lot about how to work with Node.JS, npm, bower and more, and I've been trying to setup a project so I can get to work.

That's when things went wrong... I've done web in PHP and ASP.NET MVC, where I had a very clear image of how the folders should look and where every new file should go. So far, with MEAN, I'm baffled.

I've tried starting with what the tutorial gave me and work from there. Then I realized the tutorial completely neglected to deal with things like where to put external libraries, how does bower fit in (which seems basic?), or where and how to unit test my code.

I've found two template seed projects since - one is [too sparse](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo) (no angular, hardly any client-side code), one is [WAY too complex](https://github.com/pilwon/ultimate-seed) (why do I even need redis when I'm working with mongo?).

My current wish-list includes: grunt for devops; bower for external client-side libraries; qunit for testing on both client and server; as well as the MEAN bundle (Mongoose, angular, express), and the usual goodies (jQuery, materialize). I also need a simple way to add new external libraries (ex: angular-file-upload, for starters), which I heard bower does well.

What template or hierarchy do you recommend, and why? How do you deploy? What do you need to do when you need to create a new JS file? When you need to add an external library? When you add a new page? When you write new tests, client + server? How do you run your tests - client + server?

Thanks :)

Comment: I cannot give you correct answers, since I am just getting into MEAN stack, but currently I am half way through this book "Mean Web Development" by Amos Q. Haviv. The book talks you through creating no-trivial application with user authentication and testing but with no talk about Bower or Grunt. IMHO, Bower is the simplest of all the JS tools available and configuring Grunt is more or less the same, no matter what's the tech stack you are working with.

Comment: They seem simple, but there are many glitches when I try to make them work together. Ex: bower files need to sit inside public folder. Grunt 'concat' then tries to include them in my final js file. I need them excluded... This is obviously solvable, but it is just one of many problems that pop up and distract me from actually working

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for too many things.
It's important to understand that ExpressJS is very flexible and you can structure your application as per your requirement. It is completely in your hands whether you want to break everything and make it modular or just keep everything in one file(which is obviously not recommended) and work with it.
Since you are starting out do learn about [middle wares](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html), [express serve static](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in), [express generators](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html), [database integration](http://expressjs.com/guide/database-integration.html)

Once you get an idea about above mentioned topics i think it will be fairly easy to get started. In MEAN we basically use express as backend framework, it provides us API's and we consume those API's from AngularJS services.

So let's come to point about **project structure**.
You can keep folder 'app' for server related stuffs, 'client' folder for client side javascript/Angularjs stuffs, 'test' for all the test scripts.

For testing you can use [mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha), [chai](http://chaijs.com) , [expect](https://github.com/Automattic/expect.js), [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) they are very good.

To automate the management of javascript libraries, you can use **bower**. in **bower.json** you just have to mention the client side library and the version you want then bower will take care of everything else. You can even use some [grunt tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-copy) to download the bower dependencies for you and put it in which every folder you want. With grunt you can even automate tasks such as running the test scripts, minifying etc.

**Why to Redis when we have MongoDB?**

To implement persistent session store, Redis is just perfect.

**How do you deploy?**

To get you started try with [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction), they have nice [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction). After that you can move it to any cloud servers it works more or less the same.

**What template or hierarchy do you recommend, and why?**

There are lot of good mean seed projects available which you can follow such as [MEAN.js](http://meanjs.org), [MEAN.io](http://learn.mean.io), [draftmonk mean](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) and many more in github. And yes even i got one which i am still working on([link](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-passport-auth)).
You can look into hierarchy of any of the projects mentioned above, that will give you a good idea.

If you want to make it more scalable and robust then implement **Redis** and **RabbitMQ**, your project will be rock solid.

**When you need to add an external library?**

In express for doing certain specific tasks there are bunch of npm modules written already which we use very often. Many of the modules come default but if you need you can add their entry in package.json file and use them in project. Similarly for client side you would need certain external libraries which you would need to reference in your views.

**How to you run tests?**

You can manually run your scripts as `node file-name.js` or you can automate them with grunt.

**When you write new tests, client + server?**

Whenever you add new feature, it's good habit to update test script too. Or some people prefer to write test script first then the actual code. So it depends.

I think i answered almost all, let me know if i missed any or you need more clarity.